# call to onBlur gives TypeError: (destructured parameter) is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

With following code, onChange works OK, printing something to console as expected. But using onBlur gives error:
TypeError: (destructured parameter) is undefined

Why is that?

Also odd for me, is that if I remove the event from the functions and leave definition only like: 
const handleValueChange = ({value}) => {

then onChange prints 
value undefined

while it is not giving the error though. With the event in place, it prints as expected
value test [added with the key pressed]

But on all occations, onBlur gives the error about destructured parameter is undefined

The code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const Test = () => {

    const handleValueChange = (event, {value}) => {
        event.persist();

        console.log('value', value);
    };

    const handleBlur = async (event, {value}) => {
        event.persist();      

        console.log('value', value);
    };


    return (
        <Form name='testForm'>
            <Form.Field>
                <Form.Input
                    placeholder='Name'
                    label='Name'
                    name='name'
                    key='key'
                    value='test'
                    onChange={handleValueChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
            </Form.Field>
        </Form>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onBlur` only provides one argument, the `event`.  So you'll want to destructure that if you want the value like

```
const handleBlur = async (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  // OR
  // const { target: { value } } = event;
  event.persist();      

  console.log('value', value);
};
```